# How to read out numbers with scientific notation?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

I apologize about my question which seems too easy to be a question.
I'm unable to find anywhere that shows how to say numbers in scientific notation.
Seems like every video I see with people talking about scientific notation, they refer to it as "this number" rather than reading it aloud verbally.

For my presentation, I have a number that I'd like to read/say

> 6.634e+15

I was wondering how I would verbally say this number?
Would **6.634 times 10 to the power of 15 be correct?**

Comment: My way: "6.634 dot 10 to the (power of) 15".

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Awesome, thats what I thought. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would say that as long as it is understandable it is okay,

You can say

`6.634 times 10 to the 10`

`6.634 times 10 to the power of 10`

Or anything along those lines.

You can also use the [Metric perfix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) way:

`6.634 peta`

Or

`6634 tera`

And if it is in context even

`6.634 p`

Or

`6634 t`

Answer (score 2):

Say "six point six three four times ten to the fifteenth".

If this is the amount of some quantity with a metric name you can say

"six point six three four  petawhatevers"

Comment: why to the minus/negative?

Comment: Because I misread the question. Will fix thanks.